# Materialized view stuck in creation

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I dropped a materialized view while it was still being made but now its stuck in the system.views_builds_in_progress table - how can I clear it out so I can try remaking the view?

Each node is on a different generation number (one is on 'null') and isn't incrementing/decrementing.

Comment: Any resolution to this? Encountering the same issue

Comment: We ran into this during the evaluation phase of cassandra and the only solution we found was to nuke the cluster and start fresh.

Comment: Thanks. I asked a similar question after I posted my comment...see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40553499/stop-cassandra-materialized-view-build

Comment: Same problem here, no idea how to proceed to completely remove the materialized views.