# Stop Cassandra Materialized View Build

Tags: database, cassandra

Is there any way to stop the build of a materialized view in Cassandra (3.7)?

Background: I created two materialized views **A** and **B** (full disclosure - I may have attempted to drop them before the build was complete) and those views seem to be perpetually stuck...any attempt to create another view **C** on the same table seems to hang. Using nodetool

```
nodetool.viewbuildstatus <keyspace>.<view>
```

shows a combination of STARTED and UNKNOWN for **A** and **B**, and STARTED for views in **C**. Using cql:

```
select * from system.views_builds_in_progress
```

all views are listed, but *generation number* and *last_token* have not changed in the last 24hrs (*generation_number* is in fact null for **A**).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not documented, but `nodetool stop` actually takes any compaction type, not just the ones listed (which the view build is one of). So you can simply:

```
nodetool stop VIEW_BUILD
```

Or you can hit JMX directly with the `org.apache.cassandra.db:type=CompactionManager` mbean's `stopCompaction` operation.

All thats really gonna do is set a flag for the view builder to stop on its next loop. If it threw an uncaught exception or something so its no longer doing anything (worth checking system/output logs) the stop wont do anything either. In that case its not really hurting anything though so can ignore it and retry. Worst case restart the node.

Comment: Ahh, that's the command I was looking for. Thanks! Seems building the view is throwing an exception `Mutation xxx is too large for maximum size of 16.000MiB` - it sleeps for five minutes to only error out once again (not entirely obvious why that Exception is being thrown). Will mark as solved, although my case might be unique in that the command didn't actually stop the build - it continued *ad naseam* in this error loop (only dropping the view stopped it)

Comment: do you have wide partitions or big data in the base table? Could try increasing commit log segments and batchlog limits in `cassandra.yaml` (https://support.datastax.com/hc/en-us/articles/207267063-Mutation-of-x-bytes-is-too-large-for-the-maxiumum-size-of-y-). might wanna double check your select statement in view definition.

Comment: Seems the select statement in the view was causing the issue - how, I still don't know but after making a few modifications (for example removed un-necessary columns rather than using `select *`) the view built without issue. Thanks again for your help!